# Rails understand regex differently then rubular

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, validation, testing, rubular

I wanted to do a simple regex-based email validation:

```
class EmailValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    unless value =~ /\A([\S]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || 'is not an email')
    end
  end
end
```

Which is mentioned in rails documentation.
I have checked it in rubular and everythings works fine, but in rails, emails with dot in local address fails validation for some reason (john.doe@example.com). What's weird is that it accepts any other non-whitespace characters (e.g &^%#!*() excluding @ of course).

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :email,      presence: true, length: { maximum: 64 },
                         uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, email: true
  validates :password,   presence: true, length: { in: 8..64 }
  validates :first_name, length: { in: 2..16 }, allow_blank: true
  validates :last_name,  length: { in: 2..32 }, allow_blank: true
  validates :student_id, length: { in: 5..6 }, allow_blank: true,
                         numericality: true
end
```

And failing test:

```
  test 'should validate email with special characters in local address' do
    @user.email = 'john.doe@domain.com'
    assert @user.valid?
  end
```

Whole user_test.rb

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new(email: 'johndoe@domain.com', password: 'password12',
                     first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe',
                     student_id: '112233')
  end

  # Presence validation
  test 'user validate user' do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate empty email' do
    @user.email = ''
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate blank password' do
    @user.password = '     '
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should validate blank first name' do
    @user.first_name = ''
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should validate blank last name' do
    @user.last_name = ''
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should validate blank student id' do
    @user.student_id = ''
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  # Length validation
  test 'should not validate too long email' do
    @user.password = 'a' * 65
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too long password' do
    @user.password = 'a' * 65
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too short password' do
    @user.password = 'a' * 7
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too long first name' do
    @user.first_name = 'a' * 17
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too short first name' do
    @user.first_name = 'a'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too long last name' do
    @user.last_name = 'a' * 33
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too short last name' do
    @user.last_name = 'a'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too long student id' do
    @user.student_id = '1234567'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate too short student id' do
    @user.student_id = '1234'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  # Email format validation
  test 'should not validate email with wrong format' do
    @user.email = 'john.doe@domain'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should validate email with special characters in local address' do
    @user.email = 'john.doe@domain.com'
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test 'should not validate email with special characters in domain' do
    @user.email = 'john.doe@dom_ain.com'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  # Numeric-only validation
  test 'should not validate student id with non-numeric characters' do
    @user.student_id = 'ab123c'
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  # Uniqueness validation
  test 'should not validate duplicated email' do
    @copycat_user = @user.dup
    @user.save
    assert_not @copycat_user.valid?
  end
end
```

Any idea what could be the reason for that weird behaviour?

Comment: Are you sure that this particular validation fails? You are just checking if the record is valid. But you could check the email validation specifically: assert @user.errors[:email].empty? (after @user.valid?)

Comment: I checked that and... It works, huh weird. But still, there's problem somewhere. I'll edit post and give full code right there.

Comment: I mean why it would be valid user and after I change email it becomes invalid, but there are no email related errors

Comment: You can check which errors are there by printing them in the test like p @user.errors.messages after @user.valid?

Comment: When I put print before assert it prints out `{}`. When I put after it, prints nothing.

Comment: But when I do `@user.errors.full_messages.inspect` instead it prints: `["Email has already been taken"]`. Interesting since I am doing TDD and still didn't implement creating user.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the resolution.

I had fixture with same parameters as

```
@user = User.new(email: 'johndoe@domain.com', password: 'password12',
                 first_name: 'John', last_name: 'Doe',
                 student_id: '112233')
```

Since email must be unique, it gave me an error that email has already been taken.